# Closed formula for mean

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-matrices

Suppose we have the i.i.d. random variables $X_{11}, X_{12},\ldots, X_{nn}$, such that each $X_{ij}$ has standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$, with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Given some integer $k>0$, is there some closed formula for the mean
$$E\Big(\sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k=1}^nX_{i_1i_2}X_{i_2i_3}\ldots X_{i_{k-1}i_k}X_{i_ki_1}\Big)$$

?

I worked the cases for $k=1,2,3,4$, which gave, respectively, $0,n,0,8n^2+3n$. I'm not certain about the last one, but I know the mean is $0$ if $k$ is odd.

Just for clarification, this is the mean of the trace of $X^k$, where $X$ is a random matrix (it's a square matrix) with entries $X_{ij}$, i.e., 
$$X = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
X_{11} & \ldots & X_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
X_{n1} & \ldots & X_{nn}\\
\end{array} \right]. $$

Any insight will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: If these variables are independent, the expected value should just be a large sum of products of $0$s.

Comment: No, because some of the products have all variables to even powers.

Comment: Are you assuming a normal distribution?  Otherwise you need to know all the moments, not just mean and variance.

Comment: Normal distribution $N(0,1)$, going to fix

Comment: If $n=2$ and $k=3$, then this should be $E(X_{11}X_{11}+X_{12}X_{21}+X_{21}X_{12}+X_{22}X_{22})=2$.  Right?

Comment: In your context, only the leading order term is relevant. It corresponds to paths where each edge (i,j) is used exactly twice and this counting has been extensively explained in the literature.

Comment: @Did Could you recommend me some reading?

Comment: @Gaffney You did the case $n=k=2$. In the case $n=2, k=3$ we have
$$E(\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3=1}^2 X_{i_1i_2} X_{i_2i_3} X_{i_3i_1}) = $$
$$=E(X_{11}^3+X_{11}X_{12}X_{21}+
X_{12}X_{21}X_{11}+X_{12}X_{22}X_{21}+
X_{21}X_{11}X_{12}+X_{21}X_{12}X_{22}+
X_{22}X_{21}X_{12}+X_{22}^3)=0$$

Comment: Let us stay classical: the book *An Introduction to Random Matrices* by Anderson, Guionnet and Zeitouni, probably explains this in one of the first chapters. Or Mehta.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but a suggested approach to the problem... It reduces the problem to counting certain partitions.

The approach I suggest is to go via [Isserlis' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem), which gives an expression for the product of centred normal distributions as

\begin{align*}
\mathbf E[ X_1 \cdots X_{2n} ] = \sum \prod_{p=1}^{n} E[ X_{p_1} X_{p_2} ],
\end{align*}
where the sum runs over all partitions of $\{1,\ldots, 2n\}$ into pairs $(p_1,p_2)$: i.e.
\begin{align*} \bigcup_{p=1}^n \{p_1,p_2\} = \{1,\ldots, 2n\}.
\end{align*}
This result holds in general for correlated normal variables. Noteably in the independent case, the expectation $E[X_{p_1} X_{p_2}] = 0$ unless $X_{p_1} = X_{p_2}$, and further the product $\prod_{p=1}^{n} E[ X_{p_1} X_{p_2} ] = 0$ unless $X_{p_1} = X_{p_2}$ is true for all $p=1,\ldots, n$.

The problem is now purely combinatorial: given a multiset of variables $\{X_1,\ldots, X_{2n}\}$, how many ways are there to partition the multiset into pairs such that each pair consists of two copies of the same variable?

As I said, this is not a complete answer but it does leave you with a tractable approach so long as you're willing to do some counting!